# I can't insert data with postgres + php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Well i'm working with php + postgres trying to make a web app. My problem is when i try to insert data in a table, because it don't "dies", but also does not insert anything.

This is my View, all working fine here.

```
<form action="../../Controlador/agregarAlumno.php" method="post">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Coordinador" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Rol:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="rol" placeholder="Rol USM" required="true" />
    <label for="nombre">Rut:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Área:</label>
    <select name="area">
    <option value="">Elige un área</option>
    <?php 

        foreach($areas as $area) 
        { 
           echo '<option value="'. $area[0] .'">'. $area[1] .'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>

    <label for="nombre">Teléfono:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Ej: +56988182965" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Talla Polera:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="talla" placeholder="Ej: S, M, L" required="" />
    <label for="nombre">Carrera:</label>
    <select name="carrera">
    <option value="">Elige una carrera</option>
    <?php 

        foreach($carreras as $carrera) 
        { 
           echo '<option value="'. $carrera[0] .'">'. $carrera[2] .'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>

    <label for="email">Correo Electrónico</label>
        <input id="email" type="mail" name="correo" placeholder="Ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Contraseña</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="contraseña" required="true" />


    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

This is agregarAlumno.php, the idea here is insert an User, then make it an Coordinator, in simple words, i'm trying to do 2 inserts with one view.

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");
include("../Modelo/alumno.php");
include("../Modelo/area.php");
include("../Modelo/coordinadoresArea.php"); 

$al = new alumno();

$alumnos = $al->obtenerAlumnos();
foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)
{
    if($_POST[rol] != $alumno[0] )
    {
        $al->agregarAlumno($_POST[nombre],$_POST[rol],$_POST[rut],$_POST[telefono],$_POST[talla],$_POST[carrera],$_POST[correo],$_POST[contraseña]);
    }

} 
$cor = new coordinadoresArea();
$cor->agregarCoordinadorArea($_POST[rol],$_POST[area]);
//header("Location: ../Vista/Coordinadores Area/coordinadoresArea.php"); 
?>
```

This is the function agregarAlumno:

```
function agregarAlumno($nombre,$rol,$rut,$telefono,$talla,$id_carrera,$correo,$contraseña)
  {
include("conexion.php");
$query = "INSERT INTO alumno VALUES('".$rol."','".$id_carrera."','".$nombre."','".$rut."','".$correo."','".$contraseña."','".$telefono."','".$talla."')";
return $result = pg_query($query);

pg_free_result($result);

pg_close($db);
  }
```

And here is the function agregarCoordinador:

```
function agregarCoordinadorArea($rol,$id_area)
  {
include("conexion.php");
echo "Rol:",$rol," ","Id Area:",$id_area;
$query = "INSERT INTO coordinador_area VALUES('".$rol."','".$id_area."')";
$result = pg_query($query);

pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($db);
  }
```

Finally this is the table coordinador_area:

```
CREATE TABLE coordinador_area
(
  id_coordinador_area serial NOT NULL,
  rol character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  id_area integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT coordinador_area_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_coordinador_area),
  CONSTRAINT coordinador_area_id_area_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_area)
      REFERENCES area (id_area) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT coordinador_area_rol_fkey FOREIGN KEY (rol)
      REFERENCES alumno (rol) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I'm sorry if i make a long question, but i've tried everything (that i know).

Comment: YOu are inserting 2 values in a table with 3 columns without specifying those 2 columns.`INSERT INTO coordinador_area(rol,id_area) VALUES...`

Comment: A `COMMIT` is missing.. Until that the rest of the world _never_ knew what you inserted!

Comment: All your POST parameters must be with single quote, for example:  `$_POST['nombre']`, i see you have `$_POST[nombre]` now

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar there's no need to do a COMMIT since is not working with transactions, pg_query is enought for this :)

Comment: oh, I see :p, just read the doc.. it is all implicit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your POST parameters must be with single quote, for example: `$_POST['nombre']`, i see you have `$_POST[nombre]`

Another issue is that the variable or parameters names must not contain invalid characters like `ñ`

```
$al->agregarAlumno($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['rol'],$_POST['rut'],$_POST['telefono'],$_POST['talla'],$_POST['carrera'],$_POST['correo'],$_POST['contrasenia']);
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: It works fine with $_POST[nombre] and the character ñ, the problem were in $query = "INSERT INTO coordinador_area VALUES('".$rol."','".$id_area."')"; . Many thanks anyway.